# Delete files after deleting a specific row of a table

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I have a table that store the ADDRESS of uploaded files. e. g. "upload/news/pic1.jpg" .

Now my question is:

How can I delete these uploaded files after deleting rows from table. Is there a way to do this automatically? I can't let them stay on host permanently!

thanks...

Comment: No, there's no way to do it automatically. You need to write explicit code in your script to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the file names and delete the files.

```
foreach ($files as $filepath) {
    unlink('/path/to/root/'.$filepath);
}
```

*Then* delete the file names from the database.

Computers are stupid. They will only do something if you tell them to do it.